# unable to print a document from WSL ubuntu

Tags: printing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed WSL and WSL2 and I am trying to print a document from Ubuntu WSL. But unfortunately, I can't install the driver for the printer. I'm getting these errors:

[[image: description of error]][]

In WSL, I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to install hplip-3.20.3.run but I'm getting

[image: another description]

When I am even trying to install python-pyqt5, the message says it's already installed. I don't know what to do. Does it mean that we cannot print in WSL?

Comment: On normal Ubuntu the simple `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` would be enough, not sure about WSL.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/999241/getting-cups-and-printing-working-on-ubuntu-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: Do you have `cups` installed?

Comment: Hi all. @BrianZ, yes I have it installed but it was not working. I worked around cups and finally it's working. I am preparing all the steps to post it here how i manage to get cups working. The filter in cups was throwing an error and cups did not install all the necessary files.